# Javascript (Vue.js) not working in mobile and other connected devices but it is working on the desktop where the localhost is running

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, vue.js

I tried running my laravel project on localhost then I tried connecting it on another mobile devices and desktops/laptops via the localhost address. When I tried to run the function on the desktop that has been hosting the localhost, it is working, but in other devices, it is not working. Here is my code for javascript.

I tried to look at my inspect and this is what i got.

"Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

[image]

This is my script that is not working:

```
<script>
const app = new Vue({
    el:'main',
    data:{
        dropdown: [],
        selected: null,
        trans:{}

    },
    mounted(){
        this.getTrans();

    },
    methods:{
        getTrans(){
            axios.get('http://localhost/dqrs/api/transactions')
            .then((response)=>{
                this.trans=response.data
            })

            .catch(function (error){
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        setDropdown: function (type) {
                    this.selected = null;
                    this.dropdown = this.trans[type];
                    console.log(type)
                    }

    }
})
```

Comment: There will be no server running on `localhost` on your mobile device, you need the ip/domain of the machine running your server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to access the website resources using `localhost` which would work on the device you are trying to run the code from. But it will not work when you try to access it from a networked device.

Make sure you haven't hard coded `localhost` as the `baseUrl` for your HTTP client (most likely `axios` in your case). Read its value from your `.env` file. Lastly, when you are serving the application, specify your device's IP address as the host using the `--host` option.

```
php artisan serve --host=<your-device-IP>
```

Comment: Hi! I already fixed it using Laravel- CORS but my poblem is it is still not working on mobile devices. The javascipt function is not working.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, `axios.get('http://localhost/dqrs/api/transactions')` will not work. You have to replace `localhost` with your device's IP address. If you've already done that and still facing problems, there might be a firewall blocking access.

Comment: You're the best dude! How did I miss that logic. Thanks very much!